# I always get manifest merger error while trying to install admob

Tags: android, admob

I tried to add admob in my project and I also tried to add `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` in application in the manifest but at this time it gives another error:

> `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` inside of `<application>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admobessay"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission     android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>


        </application>
    </manifest>
```

My `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admobessay"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-        optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
}
```

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-30:19 to override.

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file? It looks like you're mixing up the old v4 support library and the new androidx support library.

Comment: I've updated it starts from apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to your attempt to use support libraries along with Android X dependencies, which are implemented in the last (18th) version of Google Play Services. To solve the issue you can migrate to Android X by doing the following changes to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

Replace the following lines:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

with these:

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
```

also, setting these flags to your `gradle.properties` file in project root directory might help:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: I was get this kind of error in React Native and i decided to change the platform and when i see this error i was so angry about this. so Thank you so much.